# Deployment to heroku with "private" config file

Tags: git, heroku, deployment

I have my config file for a node app in the gitignore list so it won't be visible at Github repo... but it won't be there when I'll try to deploy in Heroku.

What is the proper style to hide this values but them will be available in production?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have sensitive static configuration data that you want to hide then Environment Variables may be the answer. For example your Postgres User/Pass and Addon API keys are stored as environment variables on Heroku. It's only really an option for a small amount of information, not a huge configuration file. See this for how to setup config/env variables:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

If you want to keep the file, then I found this: [How to hide connection string, user name, pw when using source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176918/how-to-hide-connection-string-user-name-pw-when-using-source-control). As long as you are not pushing to heroku from the remote branch (git push heroku remote) and pushing from a branch that you have on your local (git push heroku master) then the files on your box will be pushed up, not the files on github.