# Heroku config for a Django app that requires a Firebase JSON?

Tags: json, django, firebase, heroku, configuration

I have a Python Django app deployed on Heroku that uses Firebase through [the drf-firebase-auth library](https://github.com/garyburgmann/drf-firebase-auth) (which I must use for a number of reasons). I know that configuration shouldn't be checked into version control, but I'm not sure how to avoid it in my case. The drf-firebase-auth library requires the Firebase credential JSON file to be saved in my code's directory structure. How can I pass this JSON essentially via Heroku environment variables without needing to commit the JSON file to my git repo (and push to Heroku), so that I can have a proper config setup for staging/production/etc?

The drf-firebase-auth library instructs me to add this to my `settings.py` and also to save my very sensitive `firebase.json` file to my codebase:

```
DRF_FIREBASE_AUTH = {
    'FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY': 'project/config/firebase.json'
}
```

The implementation within this 3rd party library looks a bit like this:

```
import firebase_admin
from drf_firebase_auth.settings import api_settings

...

firebase_credentials = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate(
    api_settings.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY
)
firebase = firebase_admin.initialize_app(firebase_credentials)
...
```

The problem is that I would like to avoid committing this Firebase JSON to git in order to deploy to Heroku.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Manually uploading the json file gets destroyed when Heroku refreshes dynos, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to have a file that you need to manually modify once, on your server, just like your environment variables. One way to go about this is

- add (& commit) a dummy (redact or change secrets) `firebase.json` to your git
- pull the updated commit to your server & manually modify / replace the dummy `firebase.json` with the actual one

Since the json is a config file & won't change for months, you can simply ignore the local changes on your server (& make sure you don't accidentally stash / clear it). This way, you've made sure everyone has the config file (local, staging & production) but you would need to change this depending on the required access level / environment.

Comment: Doesn't heroku destroy all non-committed files when refreshing dynos each day? This would destroy the manual modification method you propose here.

Comment: You seem to be right. Perhaps this related answer might do the trick - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20913855/2689986